# Using n98-magerun in Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, magerun

Usually I get the n98-magerun file by executing this command when I need it:
`wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun.phar` on my project . 
I used this in the last year, now today did the same thing and from all of the sudden when I executed it, I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method N98\Magento\Application\Console\Event::setName() in phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuildnew/httpdocs/n98-magerun.phar/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:43

Stack trace:
#0 phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuildnew/httpdocs/n98-magerun.phar/src/N98/Magento/Application.php(580): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('n98-magerun.app...', Object(N98\Magento\Application\Console\Event))
#1 phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuildnew/httpdocs/n98-magerun.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(122): N98\Magento\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuildnew/httpdocs/n98-magerun.phar/src/N98/Magento/Application.php(625): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuildnew/httpdocs/n98-magerun.phar(22): N98\M in phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuildnew/httpdocs/n98-magerun.phar/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php on line 43
```

I believed that somehow composer is to blame so I did a composer update but I'm still getting the error. Any idea why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. What happens is that magerun includes Mage.php from your Magento project and this on its turn includes the autoloader from your project.

Your project has a dependency on a different version of symfony/event-dispatcher.

In our case Magerun symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.8.16) while our project depends on symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.3.8) We downgraded our dependencies in the Magento project to match the versions of magerun.

Hope this helps your case.